# Getting rows for Current date with time intervals

Tags: mysql, datetime

MYSQL --
I have a table "readings" which gets realtime readings every few minutes , it has a DATETIME column "read_time".I want to get rows for current date with time intervals of 30mins :

Example:
-if current date is "2011-11-06" (YYYY-MM-DD) then :

Get rows as soon as today starts till it end of day interval of 30mins...

get rows between "2011-11-06 00:00:00" to "2011-11-06 00:30:00"

then later another query between "2011-11-06 00:30:00" to "2011-11-06 01:00:00"

this will go on till today date ends....

NEED HELP !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,30,'2011-11-06');

but you should use loop function from programming language.

Comment: Thanks alot Feruttin ,now i know how to get it , been trying to get that answer for the past 3 days :)

Comment: select *FROM readings WHERE read_time>=TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,0,CURDATE()) AND read_time<=TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,30,CURDATE());